# undefined method 'delete' for String:Class when using Mongoid and creating records via console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class SearchService
  include Mongoid::Document

  key :name, String
  field :url, String
  field :searchBaseUrl, String

  validates_presence_of :name, :url, :searchBaseUrl
  validates_uniqueness_of :name 
end
```

The first issue here is that I was using `validates_presence_of` incorrectly or so it would seem. I commented the line out and I could create the class instance at the console with no problem. But when I tried to create the object with validates_presence_of in place I got an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for String:Class
from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.3.3/lib/mongoid/fields.rb:230:in `add_field'
from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.3.3/lib/mongoid/fields.rb:145:in `field'
```

Is this error message meaningful? I'm having a hard time seeing the relationship between a missing method on the String class and me using `validates_presence_of` incorrectly. If I could pick only one thing about Ruby that bugs me it would have to be terrible error messages.

The [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) say that validates_presence_of is for association. But the [mongo db page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails) says that it's used for required fields. Are the mongodb docs incorrect?

I'm trying to decide if this is an issue I should report to the mongoid team or if I'm just not understanding how the language works.

**Update**: OK now I'm getting a very similar error in a class that doesn't use validates_presence_of at all. So it's some other issue (even though commenting out that line fixed it initially).

**Update2**: This appears to me to be bug in mongoid. Changing this line:

`field :name`
to
`field :name, String`

will cause the error to show up. Seems that any field that is defined with a type will mess up mongoid. Or those aren't supposed to be there anymore? The mongodb docs (linked above) have code that looks like `key :votes, Integer, :default => 0` so if it isn't valid the docs are wrong.

Rails 3.1.1, Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Which version of Rails are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use incorrect syntax for field type definition. It should use options hash and key "type". Example from from documentation http://mongoid.org/

```
class Artist
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :instruments
end
```

You refer to MongoMapper examples, but use Mongoid ))

Comment: Ah, I see, so the class definition in the docs is dependent on MongoMapper. Odd. I'm from C# world, that's a strange dependency to me.

Comment: jcollum, you are using mongoid not mongomapper. Please make sure you are referring to the right set of docs. The mongoid documentation is rather good.

Comment: @Tyler agreed, it is very good. I was just thrown off by the way Ruby does this stuff vs C# (my background).

Answer (score 2):

jcollum, the problem is coming from the fact that you are using mongoid but the examples on mongodb.org are using mongomapper.

Please be aware that these are different ODMs for rails and have slightly different syntax for defining fields.

Please see the documentation [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/fields.html) for mongoid.

The format for the fields using mongoid:

```
class Person
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :first_name, type: String
    field :middle_name, type: String
    field :last_name, type: String
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, you should be using the [new style validations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#validations):

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :url, :presence => true
validates :searchBaseUrl, :presence => true
```

Use `with_options` to make it DRYer

```
with_options :presence => true do |v|
  v.validates :name, :uniqueness => true
  v.validates :url
  v.validates :searchBaseUrl
end
```

Comment: I thought it might be causing the issue - the old style might not work with recent versions of Mongoid

Comment: Ah, that's a decent possibility. I find the old style validations easier to read.